# How to receive both onTapDown (eagerly) and onDoubleTap?

Tags: flutter

I'd like to perform some interaction:

- when an initial touch (onTapDown) happens (e.g. clear existing selections), AND
- when a double tap happens (onDoubleTap) happens (e.g. highlight a new selection)

Using a GestureDetector:

- if only register a onTapDown, the callback is called immediately at the first touch
- if I register both onTapDown and onDoubleTap, and the user performs a simple tap, it takes some considerable time until the onTapDown event is called (1/2 a second?). If I update the display following the tap, for the user, this feels like rendering jank -- but it in fact just getting the event to late.

Is there a way to eagerly receive onTapDown AND onDoubleTap? (Its OK, in fact preferred, if I get 2 events on a double tap).

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

// 1. double tap the green box
// 2. single tap the green box again and that it takes a long
//    time to update the text
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Playground',
      home: Material(child: SafeArea(child: content())));

  Widget content() {
    final controller = TextEditingController(text: "-");

    return Center(
        child: Column(children: [
      GestureDetector(
          onTapDown: (_) {
            controller.text = "tap down";
//            print("[${DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch}] tap down");
          },
          onDoubleTap: () {
            controller.text = "double tap ";
//            print("[${DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch}] double tap");
          },
          child: Container(
              color: Colors.green,
              width: 200,
              height: 200,
              child: Center(child: Text("Tap me")))),
      Container(
          color: Colors.red,
          width: 200,
          height: 200,
          child: Center(child: TextField(controller: controller)))
    ]));
  }
}

main() => runApp(MyApp());
```

Comment: `GestureDetector.onLongPressDown` fires immediately even if `onDoubleTap` is registered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A hacky way to do it I suppose, but you can use a `Listener` for `onPointerDown`. The code below should log `tap down` twice when you double-tap:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => MaterialApp(title: 'Flutter Playground', home: Material(child: SafeArea(child: content())));

  Widget content() {
    final controller = TextEditingController(text: "-");

    return Center(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          GestureDetector(
              onDoubleTap: () {
                controller.text = "double tap";
                print("double tap");
              },
              child: Listener(
                onPointerDown: (_) {
                  controller.text = "tap down";
                  print("tap down");
                },
                child: Container(
                  color: Colors.green,
                  width: 200,
                  height: 200,
                  child: Center(
                    child: Text("Tap me"),
                  ),
                ),
              )),
          Container(
            color: Colors.red,
            width: 200,
            height: 200,
            child: Center(
              child: TextField(controller: controller),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

main() => runApp(MyApp());
```

Answer (score 3):

Use gesture_x_detector plugin.

```
XGestureDetector(
  bypassTapEventOnDoubleTap: true,
  doubleTapTimeConsider: 170
  child: ...
)
```

Comment: Carefully. I found out that many functions of this plugin do not work on Android. Only on iOS